# apache rewrite is doing redirect

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

In apache2 rewrite is doing redirect when i am writing following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule  ^id/(.*)$ http://pickyourjersey.com/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

and if i am removing NC then it shows error

Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at pickyourjersey.com Port 80

If i am using relative path it works fine

Comment: Rewriting to a full URL will always result in a redirection - what else would you expect?

Comment: Apart from that it is unclear what you actual question is...

Answer (score 0):

replace with 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^id/(.*)"   "http://pickyourjersey.com/index.php?id=$1" [NC,L]

Comment: I have done this but it is giving internal server error

Comment: Error log is saying that

Comment: /var/www/pickyourjersey.com/public-html/.htaccess: RewriteEngine must be On or Off, referer: http://pickyourjersey.com/id/2